Can you "spot" the pattern?
Below are 15 words and 14 patterns of coloured spots. Each of the listed words can be matched to one of the spot patterns via a systematic rule - but two of the listed words match to the same spot pattern.
For the checkmark, (i) identify which words match to which spot pattern (and which two words match to the same spot pattern), (ii) clearly explain the rule behind the matching, and (iii) describe the spot pattern (not depicted here) that would match to the word 'DEFRAUD'.

Word list: APPARATUS, BEAR, BONE, CLIMBER, CREAM, DESERT, GRUESOME, HOOLIGAN, INSTEAD, MARSH, NEAR, PEN, STAR-SIGN, VAST, YOUTH.
Spot patterns: Red-Orange-Yellow-Violet, Red-Orange-Green-Blue, Red-Orange-Green-Indigo-Violet, Red-Yellow-Indigo-Violet, Red-Yellow-Violet, Red-Green-Indigo-Violet, Red-Blue-Violet, Orange-Yellow-Green-Violet, Orange-Yellow-Blue-Violet, Yellow-Green-Blue-Indigo-Violet, Yellow-Green-Violet, Yellow-Blue, Green-Blue, Blue-Indigo-Violet.

The pattern for "DEFRAUD" would be:

 yellow – green – indigo – violet

First, some observations:

 The colours of the dots correspond to the seven classical colours of the rainbow. These colours are often just abbreviated to their first letters, ROY G BIV for an easy mnemonic.

 The given words don't suggest any relationship to these letters at first sight. For example, there are eight patterns with a yellow spot ("Y"), but only one of the words has a Y.

But ...

 ... some of the words have synonyms that are made up entirely of the rainbow letters. IVY ("climber"), IVORY ("cream") and VIRGO ("star-sign") are obvious ones.

 Unfortunately, yellow – indigo – violet isn't one of the given patterns.

But, but ...

 ... we can reverse the pattern. That is, the patterns are the full set of the seven rainbow colours after the appropriate colours have been removed. That means IVY is represented by red – orange – green – blue.

The patterns are:

    APPARATUS — RIG     — orange – yellow – blue – violet
         BEAR — YOGI    — red – blue – violet
         BONE — RIB     — orange – yellow – green – violet
      CLIMBER — IVY     — red – orange – green – blue
        CREAM — IVORY   — green – blue
       DESERT — GOBI    — red – yellow – violet
     GRUESOME — GORY    — blue – indigo – violet
     HOOLIGAN — YOB     — red – green – indigo – violet
      INSTEAD — OR      — yellow – green – blue – indigo – violet
        MARSH — BOG     — red – yellow – indigo – violet
         NEAR — BY      — red – orange – green – indigo – violet
          PEN — BIRO    — yellow – green – violet
    STAR-SIGN — VIRGO   — yellow – blue
         VAST — BIG     — red – orange – yellow – violet
        YOUTH — BOY     — red – green – indigo – violet

 The pattern that occurs twice is the one for BOY / YOB.

ROB is a synonym for "DEFRAUD" that uses only the given letters.

Or, to account for the visual tag:

 

 I found the "visual" tag a bit misleading. But the visual representation of the dots makes for pretty eye candy, or to stay with the theme, an ORB ORGY. :)


Exactly right. Well deduced :) The last colour diagram is a nice touch and makes things very easy for readers to follow. (An aside: Regulars who are used to my alternative transcriptions for the colour-blind may have cottoned on to the fact I didn't abbreviate any of the names this time and wondered why... Hopefully all is now clear!)
